# Extract result after sendkeys operartion stored inside element inside href selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<td><a href="mcc.php" target="blank">Mobile Country Code</a></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="other-text" size="15" name="mcc" placeholder="201< MCC <751" title="201< MCC <751" pattern="[0-9]{3}" required="">
```

I'm using `sendKeys` in `selenium` to populate the form shown below and then, get the result computed.

[image]

Now, after when I'm done sending and populating using this code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests_html import HTMLSession

import chromedriver_binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.profonetracker.com/loc/cell-tracker")

mcc = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="mcc")
mnc= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="mnc")
lac= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="lac")
cell_cid= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="cid")
#mcc = WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#a1"))) 

mcc.send_keys("404")
mnc.send_keys('873')
lac.send_keys('10023')
cell_cid.send_keys('19874')
```

**I want to get the result, but the issue is when you open the site, the `div` where the result will be stored after computing is empty initially.**

[image]

After result is computed,
[image]

I want to extract the long & lat as :

```
Lat=26.306076 Lon=73.059769
```

Trying these out gives me **not found error or None value**,

```
element = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="gsm")
print(element.text)
print(element.get_attribute("css=a@href"))


driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//a[@href="http://www.profonetracker.com/app/map.php?var=cell&mcc=404&mnc=60&lac=10700&cid=46655"]')


driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[contains(@href,"http://www.profonetracker.com/app/map.php?var=cell&mcc=404&mnc=60&lac=10700&cid=46655")]').click()
```

Can somebody help me extracting the result which is computed from the same session. Here is the [site](http://www.profonetracker.com/loc/cell-tracker) for reference

Answer (score 0):

1. You would need explicit wait.
2. In your screenshot you are filling different value, and in your script you are filling the different value.
3. Use `.text` or `get_attribute` with `innerText`

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("http://www.profonetracker.com/loc/cell-tracker")
mcc = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="mcc")
mnc= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="mnc")
lac= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="lac")
cell_cid= driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="cid")

mcc.send_keys("404")
mnc.send_keys('60')
lac.send_keys('10700')
cell_cid.send_keys('46655')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Search']"))).click()
lat_lon = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#gsm a"))).get_attribute('innerText')
print(lat_lon)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

[image]